# Programmatically installing APK. What activity is needed in the APK being installed?

Tags: android, android-intent

I'm trying to install an APK from within my app. I have seen all the examples out there that show the Intent to use. Usually something along these lines:

```
Uri apkUrl = Uri.parse(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Download/" + "Test.apk");
Intent promptInstall = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW).setDataAndType(apkUrl, "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
startActivity(promptInstall);
```

When I run it though I get the exception:

```
android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=/storage/emulated/0/Download/Test.apk typ=application/vnd.android.package-archive }
```

I'm new to android. But I guess this means that Test.apk needs an activity in it's manifest xml for the ACTION_VIEW intent. But I'm not sure how to write it or if it needs an activity associated with it in the source files? Or what are the requirements for the apk to BE installed?

Thanks!
Kyle

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error indicates that Android cannot find any installed activity that can handle the request to VIEW the given URI. It has nothing to do with the code that is inside the APK.

Your problem is that your URI has no scheme, it isn't properly formatted. The URI should look like this:

```
`file:///storage/emulated/0/Download/Test.apk`
```

To fix it you can do something like this:

```
File apkFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Download/" + "Test.apk");
Uri apkUrl = Uri.fromFile(apkFile);
```